# Connecting MariaDB on GCP using Micronaut Framework

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mariadb, micronaut

Is the JDBC url proper?

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:mysql://myDB?cloudSqlInstance=<<GCP_ProjectID>>:<<ZONE>>:             <<MYSQL_INSTANCENAME>>&useSSL=false
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    username: <<USERNAME>>
    password: <<PASSWORD>>
    schema-generate: UPDATE
    dialect: MYSQL
    maximumPoolSize: 15
    minimumIdle: 5
```

Comment: why do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-connectors#setup-and-usage) and I found out that the URL you're using is different from the example provided for [JDBC](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md#creating-thejdbc-url):

```
jdbc:mysql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<MYSQL_USER_NAME>&password=<MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD>
```

Please apply the above information accordingly with your **DATABASE_NAME** / **INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME** / **MYSQL_USER_NAME** / **MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD**
and let me know the results.